# How to map :!ruby % to a key combination in gvim?

Tags: ruby, vim

I want to map `:!ruby %` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> in gvim, but I can't understand exactly how.

So, I know that there are different type of maps working in different modes - normal, visual, insert, etc. What I tried doing is adding `:map <C-j> :!ruby %` to vimrc and it's not working. The error is:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>100_Move
```

Also, vim.wikia.com lists this as an example map

```
:map <F2> :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>
```

What does `<CR>` stand for? I've seen it in a lot of the example commands there.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
:nmap <C-j> :!ruby %<CR>
```

- `nmap` - normal mode map
- `<CR>` - is like hitting enter

Comment: Yes, it worked! So Ctrl + j was taken by something else? Thank you very much!

Comment: Likely, [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) u can find more info

Answer (score 1):

```
map  --> insert+normal+operator-pending mapping
imap --> insert mode mapping
nmap --> normal mode mapping
omap --> operator-pending mapping
cmap --> command-line mapping
vmap --> visual+select mode mapping
xmap --> visual mode mapping
smap --> select mode mapping
```

It is a good idea to be as specific as possible.

See `:help map-modes` and, more generally, `:help map.txt`.

Also see `:help key-notation` for the meaning of `<CR>` (already explained by nomad) and other special keys.